# Ceramic Stain: Removal (from hot water tank)

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile

I was adjusting the hot water tank this afternoon and draining the tank just as part of maintenance since it hadn't been done in who knows how long.  The tank looks fairly new (no more than 5 years old) (I'm renting this house).

Plus, on a side note, our hot water upstairs has been VERY poor.

Overall, my hot water issues were fixed after adjusting the hot water thermostat, but while removing the water hose from the drain valve, some water spewed out of the house due to the pressure.  Not that much water hit the ceramic type, and I was able to wipe it up pretty fast.

My issue is this, after this happened, I noticed on one tile there is a fairly large stain.  The tile is a white beigeish color.  The stain is almost a grayish stain that you can really tell due to the tile color.

Does anyone know what this stain could be from (why did water stain my tile) and what is the best way to get rid of the stain, besides replacing the tile?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a rust stain. I would go with a product like CLR.

But, before trying it, try it on a spare uninstalled tile to be sure it won't do more damage to the tile than the stain.

These products are very caustic, so don't underestimate them! Heed the instructions carefully regarding sitting time, use of personal safety equipment, and thoroughly rinsing the tile afterward.